# WHERE statement with unknown number of select criteria

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building web service script. Script receives user preferences for categories in the form of a string - for instance ,1,5,6,8,15,. I need to select all records from database table whose categories corresponds to categories user has selected.

I need SELECT which will return A, D and E records in this case.

Maybe the best approach would be to explode string, and do a loop for each sub-string with query with different WHERE condition in every iteration?

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id + record1 + category +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1  +   A     +     5    +
+ 2  +   B     +     20   +
+ 3  +   C     +     7    +
+ 4  +   D     +     1    +
+ 5  +   E     +     6    +
+ 6  +   F     +     3    +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to explode the string and produce a query that looks like:

```
select *
from table t
where id in (1, 5, 6, 8, 15);
```

This would allow the query to be optimized using an index on `id`.

Note that this is different from a condition like:

```
where id in (@values)
```

In that case, `@values` would be treated as a single string with a value of `1,5,6,8,15`, and would presumably match no rows.

As Juergen points out, you can use `find_in_set()` for this purpose.  That solution cannot take advantages of an index on `id`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from your_table
where find_in_set(id, @input) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how those selections are gathered. I'll assume you have them in an array, `$cats`. With this you can then use `implode()`:

```
$sql = "SELECT field FROM table WHERE category = ".implode(" || category = ", $cats);
```